Getting NaN inside <input type="number"/> (React)
I am trying to create a currency conversion site using React, and I'm stuck with a problem. Whenever I type a number inside this input<input value={sourceAmount} onChange={handleSourceAmountChange} type="number"    /> I get NaN inside <input type="number" value={targetAmount} readOnly />.
Here you can see my GitHub repository (https://github.com/Patriciagracia/currency-conversion/tree/master/src). Also, I deployed it on Vercel (https://currency-conversion-gray.vercel.app/).
Could someone offer some guidance on what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you :)
I tried adding parseFloat but it didn't work.

I checked your code here I found some issues in your code:
The first time when loaded this app in the currency selector nothing value auto selected be default which is why the default currency is empty and gives NAN.

and when you select currency then it will give the accurate results:

NOTE
You should set a default value for source currency when app load.

Thank you, I didn't realize :)
